# React.js Can't read property of undefined V18

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm making a simple app and here i make a button and pass some props to it

```
<HeaderContainer buttonToLink={'/signin'} buttonToText ={'Sign in'}>
//some code goes here
</HeaderContainer>
```

then in another file i handle it

```
export  function HeaderContainer({children , ...restpros}) {
console.log(restpros.buttonToLink,restpros.buttonToText)
return (
    <Header>
        <Header.Frame>
            <Header.Logo to={'/'} src = {Logo} alt = {'NetFlix'} />
            <Header.ButtonLink to ={restpros.buttonToLink} > <p>{restpros.buttonToText}</p></Header.ButtonLink>
        </Header.Frame>
        {children}
    </Header>
)}
```

i got the error

> **Can't read property of undefined**

and i don't know why i get undefined because i pass my props to it

note : **Header.ButtonLink** is a react router link and i use styled component for styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be due to the format of your parameters in the HeaderContainer component. If you take a look at the ReactJS docs in the "Composition vs Inheritance" section here: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html it mentions how you can access children through the props object like so:

```js
    export  function HeaderContainer(props) {
    console.log(props.buttonToLink, props.buttonToText);
    return (
        <Header>
            <Header.Frame>
                <Header.Logo to={'/'} src={Logo} alt={'NetFlix'} />
                <Header.ButtonLink to={props.buttonToLink} > 
                    <p>{props.buttonToText}</p>
                </Header.ButtonLink>
            </Header.Frame>
            {props.children}
        </Header>
    )}
```

Now you should be able to use your component like before:

```js
<HeaderContainer buttonToLink={'/signin'} buttonToText ={'Sign in'}>
    <View>
        <Text>I'm a child component</Text>
    </View>
</HeaderContainer>
```

Please let me know if this works for you, if not, I will build a working example on my machine and share it with you.

Good luck :)

Comment: i use exactly what you mentioned , but i destructor it to use it easier. instead of props.children i use {children}. i didn't find any problem in passing but react say it's undefined and i cant figure it out

Comment: Yes I can see that.... But could you maybe try to refactor your code to what I have provided. I think maybe the way you use destructuring is not 100% correct.

Comment: i don't know wtf is going on , my code , that i upload it as a problem , without any changes , now working correctly, im sooooooooo confused,idid everything i could do ,reloading page, reloading vscode but now suddenly it worked :|

Comment: Well, problem solved i guess xD

Comment: do you have any idea that what is the cause of this type of problem?? this is second time that i face this type of problem and i have no idea what is the cause

Comment: Either you forget to save your file before running the code or it is a cache problem.

Comment: I could be due to a lot of things, but most likely a cache problem. You can look up online how to clear cache for vscode, npm and what other things you might be using. You could also see logs of the different tools you are using to see if it is visible what the error might be. And remember, sometimes tech is just teasing you for the heck of it (jk, there is of cause always "some" reason behind it, but sometimes a reboot of it all is all it takes). Sorry I can't be of more help than this.